# Rails : Cannot run server from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app on Windows 7 platform:

`rails new test`

then I start this server by command :

`rails server`

There is a notice :

```
rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

But when I go to browser and type : `http://0.0.0.0:3000` but I receive page not available.

It makes me headache. Please tell me how to fix this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit it at

localhost:3000

0.0.0.0 isn't the easiest IP address

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

It is for localhost IP address.

The IP address 0.0.0.0 used is reserved IP address not being used.

Answer (score 0):

install bundle before start server

```
bundle install
```